# How would I use a sub variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback

I am working with callbacks. And would love to use sub-variables

I have been trying things out, and looking online but I can't find the fix for this.

This is what I wish could happen. But I get a error when running

```
function something(callback) {
  var x = 5;

  var y = 'anything';
  var y.lol = 'hello'
  callback(x, y.lol);
}

something(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(res.lol);
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have 2 choices. Either pass `y` instead of `y.lol` or do `y.lol = {}; y.lol.lol = 'hello'`. Your bug is because `y.lol` does not have the property `.lol`, `y` has the property `.lol`, you are basically trying to `console.log('hello'.lol)` which is undefined

Comment: Also, they're not sub-variables, they are called **properties** or more accurately object properties (because everything that is not undefined can be treated as an object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as subvariable in JS. If you mean `y.lol`, this is object property and you need `y` to be object to use it. Try this:

```js
function something(callback) {
  var x = 5;

  var y = {};
  y.lol = 'hello'
  callback(x, y);
}

something(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(res.lol);
});
```